# How do I add .01 to the end of a number using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I need to add .01 to the entry in this line of code in my XSLT script `<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property = 'atom:content-item-name']"/>`. This number appears twice in my output. I only need the .01 on the second entry. How would I do that? I guess it would be in effect a counter because if there are 2 questions I'd need it to number as .02, etc.

This is the full XSLT script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math xd xhtml mml"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no" indent="no" method="xhtml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    
    <!-- attributes, commments, processing instructions, text: copy as is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- elements: create a new element with the same name, but no namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="content-item-name"/>
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="content-item-name" select="$content-item-name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- process root -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:html">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:sequence select="'&#x0a;'"/>
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- process item, pass content item name variable -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:li[@property='ktp:question']">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="content-item-name" select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property='atom:content-item-name']/@data-value"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- branching point for any interaction type-based updates -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:li[@property='ktp:question']">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="interactionType" select="//xhtml:span[@property='ktp:interactionType']"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
   
    <!-- Change content -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:ol[@class='ktp-question-set']">
    
        <xsl:variable name="content-item-name" select="xhtml:span[@property='atom:content-item-name']/@data-value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="feedbackPara"
            select="xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:stimulus']"/>
            <ol property="ktp:questionSet" typeof="ktp:QuestionSet" class="ktp-question-set">
                <li class="ktp-question-set-meta">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property = 'atom:content-item-name']"/>
                    </section>
                    <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span class="ktp-meta" property="ktp:questionSetType">shared-stimulus</span>
                    </section>
                </li>
                <li class="ktp-stimulus" typeof="ktp:Stimulus" property="ktp:stimulus">  
                                           
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:stimulus']"/>
                    
                    <p class="place-top atom-exclude">Stimulus End: Place content above this line</p>
                </li>
                <li class="ktp-question" typeof="ktp:Question" property="ktp:question">
                    
                    <section class="ktp-question-meta">
                        <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">   
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property = 'atom:content-item-name']"/>
                        </section>
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:tags']"/>
                    </section>   
                                       
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@class = 'ktp-question-stem']"/>
         
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:ol[@class = 'ktp-answer-set']"/>
            
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation']"/>
           
                </li>                
            </ol>   
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the input section where I need to pull the data-value from:

```
<section class="ktp-question-meta">
               <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta"><span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="lsac820402"></span></section>
               <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                  <span property="ktp:interactionType" class="ktp-meta">single-select</span>
                  <span property="ktp:questionType" class="ktp-meta">Assumption (Sufficient)</span>
                  <span property="ktp:difficulty" class="ktp-meta">★</span>
                  
               </section>
```

This is how I need that section to appear with the .01 added to that data-value:

```
<section class="ktp-question-meta">
   <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">
      <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="lsac820402.01"></span>
</section>
```

Comment: You call a template using <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property = 'atom:content-item-name']"/>, so I am guessing you would need to modify your template that matches xhtml:span so that it can output what you need. In your sample code you don't seem to be showing this template.

Comment: I added my full XSLT script. Does that help?

Comment: Without an input document to test it on not really.

Comment: Consider to show us a minimal input sample together with the output you want and the one you get. In general numbers are producible with `xsl:number` or `position()` or in XSLT 3 perhaps with accumulators but I haven't been able to understand how your input data looks, where you want to insert a number and whether it depends on the input data or on the number of apply-templates with that particular path you have.

Comment: I added the info from the input file and how that section needs to look on output. Thanks!